# \w will become equivalent to \p{L} in a future?

Tags: php, regex, unicode, pcre

I don't understand why with `/u` modifier `\w` doesn't work, and we have to change our regex. Not to talk about `\b`.

So anyone know if on a new version (maybe php 6?) `\w` will become the same as `\p{L}` with `/u` ?

Thanks

Comment: Nobody knows what changes PHP 6 will have (or if it ever iwill be released)

Comment: Which are all this difficulties with unicode for php?

Comment: Yes. One of the reasons why PHP 6 development was put on hold indefinitely was trouble with making it 100% unicode compatible.

Comment: I know that, i just dont' get why it's so hard for them

Comment: Because that's the way it is.

Comment: That, and also there's surprisingly small amount of people developing PHP (as contrasted to masses developing in PHP)

Comment: They should ask a donation to all PHP developers, make a GOOD team with that money and fix this problem...

Comment: However, despite the fact that it's such fun to criticise PHP, the \p{L} and /u issues is nothing to do with PHP, and everything to do with the PCRE library... PHP simply uses the PCRE library, in the same way as Perl or Python or Ruby or many other languages, and all suffer the same limitation

Comment: Can you explain in detail what you mean when you say `\w` becomes useless when using the `u` modifier?  Can you provide a specific regex and set of data that fails?

Comment: many unicode chars are not taken by \w there are many other questions on this

Comment: @MarkBaker: Perl, Python and Ruby don't use the PCRE library.

Answer (score 1):

`\w` differs with locales, and as such, it is actually handy NOT to capture strange runes or hieroglyphs in some cases, in favor of only characters considered word characters in the *desired locale*.  `\w` & `\p{L}` are functionally totally different. Configuring locales is what people should be more aware of. Use the right tool for the job, and not a sledgehammer to hammer a 1-inch nail, which substituting `\w` for `\p{L}` would be. A lot of existing functionality would break if they did change it. Also, this is entirely unrelated to the ongoing effort of making PHP unicode compatible.

Comment: are you sure? If you set locale to utf-8 \w will not match some utf8 chars

Comment: What do you mean set your locale to `utf-8`? `utf-8` is a character set that can be used for a locale, not a locale. What is the actual locale you are using (`de_DE.utf-8` for example), and what character is giving you problems?